# Unable to get sections to display in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, books, titletoc

I'm using `\documentclass[12pt]{book}` to put together a 500-page book. The .tex file is getting pretty heavy and complex. As a result, I'm running into conflicts with the ToC.

`\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` only gets me chapters even though sections and subsections are there.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xurl}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,columns=2,intoc=true,options={-s index-style.ist}]
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{totcount}

% Font Selection

\setmainfont[
 BoldFont={DMSans-Bold.ttf}, 
 ItalicFont={DMSans-Italic.ttf},
 BoldItalicFont={DMSans-BoldItalic.ttf},
 ]{DMSans-Regular.ttf}

\setmonofont{DMMono-Regular.ttf}

% Captions

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font=small,labelfont=tt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{17pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{25pt}

% Chapter Headers

\regtotcounter{chapter}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\raggedright\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{62}{56}\selectfont}
  {\huge\rmfamily\mdseries
   % magic number 20pt
   \raisebox{20pt}{\smash{\parbox[t]{3em}{\thechapter\\/\\26}}}}
  {0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}[140pt]

% Title Sizes

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{140pt}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{17pt}{20pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}

% Custom Lists

\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}

\title{Solving Product}
\author{Étienne Garbugli}

% Endnotes

\let\footnote=\endnote

\setenotez{
  backref,
  totoc=false,
  counter-format=arabic,
  split=chapter,
  split-title={\Large\chaptername\ <ref> – <title>},
}
\AfterEveryListSplit{\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}}

\NewSplitTitleTag{title}{\nameref{ch:<split-level-id>}}

\usepackage{nameref}% automatically loaded if you use hyperref

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\origchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% starred chapter, no label then
      \origchapter{#3}%
    }
    {% else add a label
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\origchapter{#3}}
        {\origchapter[#2]{#3}}%
      \expanded{\noexpand\label{ch:\arabic{chapter}}}%
    }%
}

% Footer

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\footnotesize\ttfamily{\leftmark \hspace*{55pt} \thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\footnotesize\ttfamily{\thepage \hspace*{60pt} Solving Product}}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Redefine the plain page style

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\footnotesize\ttfamily{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\footnotesize\ttfamily{\thepage}}
}

% List Styles

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=2pt,topsep=12pt}

% Indentation

\newenvironment{genind}{\begin{adjustwidth}{12mm}{}}{\end{adjustwidth}}

\newenvironment{quotlarind}{\begin{adjustwidth}{3pt}{60pt}}{\end{adjustwidth}}
\newenvironment{quotmedind}{\begin{adjustwidth}{3pt}{80pt}}{\end{adjustwidth}}

% Table of Contents Config

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\frontmatter
\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}

\section*{Sub-title A}
\section*{Sub-title B}
\section*{Sub-title C}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\section*{Sub-title A}
\section*{Sub-title B}
\section*{Sub-title C}

\end{document}
```

Here's what the ToC looks like at the moment:

[image: ToC conflicts]

Why isn't it showing the other levels? Any ideas?

Comment: `\section*` are not supposed to appear in ToC.

Comment: Because of the * ? How can I remove the numbering of sections and have them displayed in the ToC?

Comment: Yes this is the difference between `\section` and `\section*`.  Use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section title repeated}` together with `\section*`

Comment: Great. Allowed me to fix the ToC almost completely. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you do not want your sections to be numbered. The recommended way is:

```
% in the preamble
\setcounter{secumdepth}{0} % no numbers below chapters
% in the document body
\section{One} % not \section*
% text
\section{two} % not section*
% text
```

The sections will appear in the ToC but unnumbered. No need for any packages.A

Comment: Perfect. I ended up going with your suggestion. Worked perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numberless key in \titleformat:

`\titleformat{name =\section, numberless}[display] {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont\addcontentsline{toc}{section}}`